# Received my W2 but never received any paychecks

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2

I worked for a bar/restaurant that opened Feb. 14, 2020 and then covid hit a month later and then the place closed. I worked for the whole month and never received any paychecks.

I tried contacting the owner and get his assistance but got the run around. Back in October 2020 they sent me 2 checks, but I was unable to deposit them because the checks had expired. I asked them to write new updated checks but I was ignored by the owner and his assistant.

I filed with the Labor Board regarding this. However, I still received my W2. How do I file if I never received payment for the month I worked?

Answer (score 5):

You should be following the steps from the IRS for [W-2 - Additional, Incorrect, Lost, Non-Receipt, Omitted](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted/w-2-additional-incorrect-lost-non-receipt-omitted)

> **Question**
> I received an incorrect Form W-2. My former employer won’t issue me a corrected Form W-2. What should I do?
>
> **Answer**
>
> If by the end of February, your Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement has not been corrected by your employer after you attempted to have your employer or payer issue a corrected form, you can request that an IRS representative initiate a Form W-2 complaint. Call the IRS toll free at 800-829-1040 or make an appointment to visit an IRS Taxpayer Assistance Center (TAC).
>
> - The IRS will send your employer a letter requesting that they furnish you a corrected Form W-2 within ten days.
> - The IRS will send you a letter with instructions and Form 4852, Substitute for Form W-2, Wage and Tax Statement, or Form 1099-R, Distributions from Pensions, Annuities, Retirement or Profit-Sharing Plans, IRAs, Insurance Contracts, etc. You can use the Form 4852 in the event that your employer doesn't provide you with the corrected Form W-2 in time to file your tax return.

Please see link for full details.